# Traffic handling capacity for 1 EC2 instance for t3.2xlarge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Protocol exchange between phone server and IOT device(inter regional). say there are 100000 users and each are requesting or using 12 - 20 times a day may be approximately at the same time(protocols are very small less than 1 KB), so I need to create instances for protocol exchange and auto scaling, each transfer is stored as a log and a backup up-to 1000 GB

here is my instances purchasing idea
user -> Route53 -> Elastic Beamstalk - > I am -> RDS -> S3 -> cloud front

I need the traffic handling capacity for 1 EC2 instance for t3.2xlarge - vCPU's 8 - Memory - 32GB
i.e I need to know how many request at a time it can handle to estimate the cost by calculating how many EC2 instances I'll be using and also need someone to rectify my instance purchase if any

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can answer this question for you because it **totally depends on your specific application and how it is used**.

You should create some **performance tests with simulated load** to determine where bottlenecks might lie, and how much traffic an instance could handle.

Also, please note that T3-family Amazon EC2 instances are **burstable**, which means that the amount of CPU might be limited if it is highly used. (You can use the T3-Unlimited option to avoid this, but at extra potential costs.)

Comment: so, you suggest any better option which is cost effective to handle 100000 request and its not true all the time, i need it only during the peak hours, say its 5 hours a day and the remaining time will be around 10k so which ec2 instance along with elastic beanstalk

Comment: It depends on your architecture, such as whether you design it to be serverless, or run on Amazon EC2. Plus there's the language you use, your method of storage, etc. Nobody can offer you a suggestion on what is required to handle your traffic. Only _you_ will know this information, after simulating traffic or measuring actual traffic.

Comment: thank you for your time @John Rotenstein can you suggest a test tool to monitor the traffic for my calculation and can you suggest a tool to send 100000 request at a time to test, It will be very helpful

Comment: It's not just a matter of monitoring traffic. You will want to keep an eye on anything that could be the bottleneck, such as CPU, memory, disk access and database latency. he easiest way is to throw lots of requests at the system and see what breaks first. Then you know that you need to scale that component. Simulation depends on how your users would normally be accessing your system (web, API, dropping files into s3, etc). You can write your own system to send the requests, or use something like [bees with machine guns](https://github.com/newsapps/beeswithmachineguns).